# UIWebView Link Delegate

Tags: file, uiwebview, download, nsdata

What I'm trying to do is create an app that will download files of certain extensions (let's say a .mp3 file from my FTP). I want a delegate method for tapping a link in a UIWebview, and if the link ends in ".mp3", create some sort of download method that would write the file to the /Documents directory with an automatic file name.

Is there any way to achieve this? I've looked everywhere for downloading files and writing them to the /Documents directory but no answers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
      - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView
        {
            currentURL = self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
            NSLog(@"Current URL %@", currentURL);
            if ([currentURL rangeOfString:@"mp3"].location == NSNotFound) {
                NSLog(@"string does not contain mp3");   
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Found mp3");
                //Do the download here
NSString *urlString = currentURL;
            NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            [urlData writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
            if ( urlData )
            {  
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

                NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"downloadedMP3.mp3"];
                [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
            }
            }
        }
```

Don't forget to conform to the UIWebView protocol in your .h file (`<UIWebViewDelegate>`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That method is picking the links up now - but it won't work for some reason when I tap on a link that ends in .html - I get a log of: setting movie path:http://....mp3 ? Thank you :)

Comment: Just searched through all my code and it's not logged anywhere?

Comment: I've just been searching on the internet and it looks like it's coming from a JavaScript audio player? Is there any way to download the file that's being logged? Thanks for this - you're a legend!

Comment: Still coming up with the setting movie path error - thank you for your help anyway! You've pointed me in the right direction! :)

Comment: This log does not come from your code. Or it comes from another file than the one you posted.

Comment: Fixed! I was running my application from the simulator - for some reason it works fine on a device! Thank you again, sir! :)